# How to make amazon s3 files fast from anywhere in the planet?

Tags: amazon-s3, cdn, amazon-cloudfront, audio

I'm working on a project with user created content, users basically upload long mp3 files to the server which can then be played by other users.

Recently users not from europe reported slow "seek time" and "play time", so i'm wondering how could i make it fast everywhere?

One idea was to put cloudfront in front of the s3, but i guess the first user from each zone would still have a slow start?

Comment: What do "seek" and "play" time correlate to at the http/transport layer ??  I'm guessing that  it's time to first byte of content but please clarify.

Comment: It seems like CloudFront is the obvious "try this first" solution.  There could easily be an improvement in the quality of the transport between browser and S3, simply because of the traffic going through CloudFront, riding Amazon's infrastructure from the edge location back to S3, even before caching comes in to play, which, of course, would help also.

Answer (score 0):

A S3 bucket exists in a specific Amazon region, so there's no getting around speed-of-light.  Adding Cloudfront will make the 2nd play in a given edge location fast but not the first due to caching.